# Подключение к базе данных, не заработало, жду еще ответов

Tags: denwer, php, mysql

есть следующие php-файлы сайта:
authmain.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
  // if the user has just tried to log in
  $userid = $_POST['userid'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $db_conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'webauth', 'webauth');

  $query = 'select * from auth '
           ."where name='$userid' "
           ." and password=password('$password')";

  $result = mysql_query($query, $db_conn);
  if ($result->num_rows >0 )
  {
    // if they are in the database register the user id
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $userid;    
  }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Home page</h1>
<? 
  if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
  {
    echo 'You are logged in as: '.$_SESSION['valid_user'].' <br />';
    echo '<a href="logout.php">Log out</a><br />';
  }
  else
  {
    if (isset($userid))
    {
      // if they've tried and failed to log in
      echo 'Could not log you in.<br />';
    }
    else 
    {
      // they have not tried to log in yet or have logged out
      echo 'You are not logged in.<br />';
    }

    // provide form to log in 
    echo '<form method="post" action="authmain.php">';
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><td>Userid:</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="userid"></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>Password:</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Log in"></td></tr>';
    echo '</table></form>';
  }
?>
<br />
<a href="members_only.php">Members section</a>
</body>
</html>
```

members_only.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  echo '<h1>Members only</h1>';

  // check session variable

  if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
  {
    echo '<p>You are logged in as '.$_SESSION['valid_user'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>Members only content goes here</p>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo '<p>You are not logged in.</p>';
    echo '<p>Only logged in members may see this page.</p>';
  }

  echo '<a href="authmain.php">Back to main page</a>';
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  // store to test if they *were* logged in
  $old_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];  
  unset($_SESSION['valid_user']);
  session_destroy();
?>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Log out</h1>
<?php 
  if (!empty($old_user))
  {
    echo 'Logged out.<br />';
  }
  else
  {
    // if they weren't logged in but came to this page somehow
    echo 'You were not logged in, and so have not been logged out.<br />'; 
  }
?> 
<a href="authmain.php">Back to main page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

также есть база mysql, созданная в denwer

```
create database auth;
use auth;
create table auth (
name varchar(lO) not null,
pass varchar(30) not null,
primary key (name)
);
insert into auth values
( 'user', 'pass');
insert into auth values
( 'testuser', password('test123') );
grant select, insert, update, delete
on auth.*
to webauthglocalhost
identified by 'webauth';
```

При этом когда ввожу testuser и test123 в качестве пользователя и пароля мне не удается залогинится выдает Couldn't log you in

Comment: @ivan31, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($userid))
    {
      // if they've tried and failed to log in
      echo 'Could not log you in.<br />';
    }
    else 
    {
      // they have not tried to log in yet or have logged out
      echo 'You are not logged in.<br />';
    }
```

Я конечно в логику не вдавался, но

```
if (isset($userid)) // полный бред если смотреть на то что выводится, в любом случае выводится сообщение об ошибке!
Не удается войти, или вы не авторизованы.
Просто бред.
```

Не раз писал уже "Ставьте и не ленитесь кавычки!"

```
 $query = "Select * from auth where name='".$userid."' and password=password('".$password."')"; 
// неужели до сих пор кто-то пользуется в MySql ф-ей PASSWORD() ппц.

$result = mysql_query($query, $db_conn);
  if ($result->num_rows >0 ) // пашет такое?
  {
    // if they are in the database register the user id
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $userid;    
  }
```

Дальше разбираться нет желания и времени.

ппц.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
  // if the user has just tried to log in
  $userid = $_POST['userid'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $db_conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'webauth', 'webauth');

  $query = 'select * from auth '
           ."where name='$userid' "
           ." and password=password('$password')";

  $result = mysql_query($query, $db_conn);
  if ($result->num_rows >0 )
  {
    // if they are in the database register the user id
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $userid;    
  }
}
?>
```

В конец файла вставь

```
echo "<PRE>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "<PRE>";
```

И потом отпишись что выводится.

Comment: Не заработало, присылайте ответы еще

Comment: научитесь дебажить свои файлы!

Comment: Какая ошибка выводиться?

Comment: **1** Shrek, молодец просто. У меня терпение не хватит просто ответить на такой вопрос.

Comment: Дык думаешь у меня есть терпение отвечать? я так на пусть наставляю, чувствую можно будет вопрос закрыть, т.к. ТС разумного ничего не напишет.

Ps пометил как "работа за автора". ибо так и получается.

Comment: array(0) {
}

Comment: вывело array(0){}